# php server sent events chat application behaves like polling

Tags: php, polling, server-sent-events

I have started to study SSE and I found an example with php chat application (http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Server-Sent-Events-Simple-Chat-Application-Example).
The video shows that the messages are not delayed. But when I tried the example on my own server (WAMP) I have a very long delay to the point that it is no longer a real-time application as it claims. I found that if I changed the retry:15000 to a value much much smaller (for example 100 millisecond) only then getting near real-time. But this is not good. This is polling and not truly real-time application. It seems that after each message the connection to the server is lost and resets accordingly to retry. It doesn't seem like a very smart application because we have not avoided constant requests from client to server like plain Ajax polling.
Thanks

Comment: Have You try this on Your local web server ? Maybe Your hosting is a problem.

Comment: Yes the WAMP resides on my PC

Comment: Retry value you can set to 500 (0.5 s) - they use 15000 because some shared hostings have limitations. But I think better is set for one second.

Comment: Try also other solutions: https://eole-io.github.io/sandstone-doc/examples/multichannel-chat.html

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am interested for SSE. Ηowever, it seems that, contrary to what is believed, SSE ultimately leads to polling so it is useless. Except if I have to make changes in the example that I do not know. In the log I have continuous connections and disconnections but the SSE documentation explicitly mentions about a permanent connection !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we have to make an infinity loop to the server side code to keep connection opened with only one request. But this makes no sense because we turn again to old plain polling!! Or we have to write code that is synchronous waiting for something in each iteration like, for this particular example, an update of the chat.txt file.